# Alamofire with Symfony development server without valid ssl

Tags: php, swift, symfony, swiftui, alamofire

while developing an App in communication with my Backend written in PHP using symphony, I want to connect my App to my local development Server of Symfony...
I use Alamofire for the HTTP-Requests. But the local development Server does not have a valid SSL-Certificate, as it is self-signed. I already tried using a custom session and manager for setting a "cert ignore" for my Macs IP, but this didn't work anyways. This is the error I get:

```
Session was invalidated without error, so it was likely deinitialized unexpectedly. Be sure to retain a reference to your Session for the duration of your requests.
```

And this is the code:

```
let manager = ServerTrustManager(evaluators: ["192.168.2.9": DisabledEvaluator()])
let session = Session(serverTrustManager: manager)
session.request("https://192.168.2.9:8000/api/tables/1", method: .get)
    .responseDecodable(of: Table.self){response in
        ...
    }
```

What kind of error is this and what can I do against?

I am VERY new to Alamofire and would be happy if I could fix this!!!

Answer (score 0):

The error message you provided includes the solution: maintain a reference to the `Session` you created for at least the entire lifetime of the request. This is usually accomplished through the use of a singleton. In development you can simply capture the `Session` in your response handler:

```swift
.responseDecodable(of: Table.self) { response in 
    // Handle response
    _ = session
}
```

This is a quick and dirty hack that you shouldn't use for long and may run afoul of the automatic reference counting if you don't use the captured reference for anything, but it should help you get started.

Comment: thanks - just using it while on holiday without my WebServer just for local developing